# Date TimeZone conversion

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I have done conversion method from UTC String to date in local timezone, but it just returns the same date as in the String. What is wrong here?

```
 public static Date getUTCToDate(String utc){
    // String exampleOfUTCTime = "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717";

    try{
        Log.d("asd-timeBefore", "getUTCToDate: " + utc);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date d = formatter.parse(utc);
        Log.d("asd-timeAfter", "getUTCToDate: " + d);
        return d;
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are setting incorrect time zone for your formatter

Comment: What is the offset of your desired timezone?

Comment: I need to use local timezone since app will be used in various countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code, like this. It will convert UTC time zone to local time zone :

```
public static Date getUTCToDate(String utc){
    // String exampleOfUTCTime = "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717";

    try{
        Log.d("asd-timeBefore", "getUTCToDate: " + utc);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date d = formatter.parse(utc);
        Log.d("asd-timeAfter", "getUTCToDate: " + d);
        return d;
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It works! But how? I'm receiving String like `exampleOfUTCTime` so I thought I need to convert it to local timezone, but it seems that Android/Java cares by itself local timezone.

Comment: This conversion is made automatically by system. If you are setting UTC time zone -> SimpleDateFormat thinking like "Ok, this is UTC", but when you giving this to Date -> it's automaticaly converts to local time zone. Thought Date doesn't have Time Zone -> inner function has 'SimpleDateFormatter' which uses default Time Zone ( Local Time Zone )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the formatted date and time in UTC format then you should do like this

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers with `setTimeZone` are correct, but as alternative, you can try to specify `UTC` in the string itself and indicate that you are using time zone in `SimpleDateFormat` class, e.g.:

```
public static Date getUTCToDate(String utc){
    // String exampleOfUTCTime = "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717 UTC";

    try{
        System.out.println("getUTCToDate: " + utc);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
        Date d = formatter.parse(utc);
        System.out.println("getUTCToDate: " + d);
        return d;
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use local timezone since app will be used in various countries.

If you want to format a date on the server side using the client's timezone, then you will have to pass the offset from GMT time in minutes *from the client side*.  Use this JavaScript code:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

then pass this offset to your method as a parameter:

```
public static Date getUTCToDate(String utc, int offsetInMinutes) {
    // String exampleOfUTCTime = "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717";

    try {
        Log.d("asd-timeBefore", "getUTCToDate: " + utc);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
        long offset = -1L*60*1000*offsetInMinutes;
        String[] timezones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(offset);
        formatter.setTimeZone(timezones[0]);
        Date d = formatter.parse(utc);
        Log.d("asd-timeAfter", "getUTCToDate: " + d);
        return d;
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Comments:**

You'll notice that I included `Z` as a date format parameter in your `SimpleDateFormat`.  This will inlcude the time zone displayed as an offset in hours from GMT time.

A Java `Date` is simply a point in time without regard to an offset.  If you want timezone information from the client, you will have to bring it in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717" ).atZone( ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

## Details

Your input string is *not* a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time_Coordinated) value: `2016-09-27T19:35:32.717`. That String lacks any information about [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse that string as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object lacking any offset or time zone.

That input string happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time strings. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-09-27T19:35:32.717" );
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

If by context you know for certain that string was meant to represent a moment in UTC, then apply an offset to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Use the predefined constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atZone( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

From there you can use `DateTimeFormatter` to generate Strings in various formats, if needed.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to view that same moment through the lens of some particular region’s time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

You can get the user’s current default time zone if desired. But be aware this default can change at any moment, even *during runtime*. So if important, you should ask the user for intended/desired time zone rather than assume.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: This is more than enough and expected. Gotta check these - looks interesting!